# Instantiate mockup model with codeception

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, codeception

I'm doing some unit testing with laravel using codeception

I have a mock model class that goes like this

```
<?php namespace framework\tests\unit\mockModel;

    use \Codeception\Stub;
    use project\mvc\model\modelPermissionLevel;
    use project\mvc\model\modelUser;
    use project\mvc\model\modelApplicantsRestriction;

    class mockModels
    {
    }
```

and my test class goes like this

```
<?php
use framework\tests\unit\mockModel\mockModels;

class blAuthenticationTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{ 
    protected function _before()
    {
        $this->mockModels = new mockModels();
    }
}
```

it showing me an error  [Error] Class 'framework\tests\unit\mockModel\mockModels' not found. I don't know where I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

I use the **require** instead of *use*, for some reason when I'm instantiating a class at the framework directory it produce an error, don't know if that's some limitation of laravel.